# Matrix multiplication range queries

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

I have a huge list of matrix i.e A = {M0, M1, M2 .. Mn}.
I have a task to find the product of all the matrices in a given range {x,y} i.e M<sub>x</sub> * M<sub>x+1</sub> * M<sub>x+2</sub> ... * M<sub>y</sub>.

I would like to know if there is any algorithm or data structures that might efficiently compute this query.

I have tried creating a 2D matrix of all possible combination of range but as my initial matrix is very big this does not seem like a practical solution.

Comment: Are the matrices invertible?

Comment: Are there any relations between the ranges?

Comment: Efficiently for many different ranges {x,y}? Or all possible ranges {x,y}? Or only a few? What order of magnitude is n?

Comment: Also, generally, how long are the ranges?

Comment: @DocBrown The Matrix are invertable

Comment: @Euphoric x,and y are random between {0, 10^6)  and x< y, therefore the  range  is quite variable.

Comment: Also for the moment I am only dealing with invertable matrices that are of size 2x2.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the hint. As the matrix is invertable I can just keep and array of the cumulative and then divide it.

Comment: @DocBrown but the problem with this approach is that for large values of M  I start getting overflow error.

Comment: I have finally solved my problem. I can be solved easily by using segment tree. Query and update takes just log(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of precomputing all the possible combinations, just precompute levels of power of 2.

So first would be M0_1=M0*M1, M2_3=M2*M3, M4_5=M4*M5, ...

Second would be M0_3=M0*M1*M2*M3, M4_7=M4*M5*M6*M7, ...

And so on, until biggest power of 2 that is smaller than n. This will take only 2x more memory.

Then, you can pick subdivide the range so that the biggest blocks are part of the calculation. For example, for range {1,8} you would multiply M1*M2_3*M4_7*M8. That is only 3 multiplications instead of 8. In general worst case amount of multiplications is logarithmic function of length of the range.

Also, picking the proper sub-ranges might be optimized using some clever binary logic. So that part has constant time complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have build an array as you have suggested. Can you tell me the most optimal way of forming my query.